# Rust thread workers taking multiple jobs at once

Tags: multithreading, http, rust, webserver, httpserver

Just trying to turn my single threaded web server into a multi-threaded one, this isn't the same one from the handbook, it's an extended one with more error handling, traits, etc. I did complete the one from the handbook aswell and am trying to implement the threadpool, I have this so far and the code builds successfully however when I test it using a /sleep path and a normal path, the same worker seems to be taking both requests instead of another worker taking the second request while the first request is being handled by the other worker, any directions appreciated :

```
pub fn run(self, handler: impl Handler) {
    println!("Listening on {}", self.addr);
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&self.addr).unwrap();
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(4);
    let handler = Arc::new(Mutex::new(handler));

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
        let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
        let handler = handler.clone();

        pool.execute(move || match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(_) => {
                println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer));

                let response = match Request::try_from(&buffer[..]) {
                    Ok(request) => handler.lock().unwrap().handle_request(&request),
                    Err(e) => handler.lock().unwrap().handle_bad_request(&e),
                };

                if let Err(e) = response.send(&mut stream) {
                    println!("Failed to send response: {}", e);
                }
            }
            Err(e) => println!("Failed to read from connection: {}", e),
        });
    }
}
```

Threadpool implementation:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
};

pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    sender: mpsc::Sender<Job>,
}

impl ThreadPool {
    pub fn new(size: usize) -> ThreadPool {
        assert!(size > 0);

        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(receiver));
        let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(size);

        for id in 0..size {
            workers.push(Worker::new(id, Arc::clone(&receiver)));
        }

        ThreadPool { workers, sender }
    }

    pub fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
    {
        let job = Box::new(f);
        self.sender.send(job).unwrap();
    }
}

type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
            println!("Worker {} got a job: executing.", id);
            job();
        });

        Worker { id, thread }
    }
}
```

Handler Trait:

```
pub trait Handler: Send + 'static {
    fn handle_request(&mut self, request: &Request) -> Response;

    fn handle_bad_request(&mut self, e: &ParseError) -> Response {
        println!("Failed to parse request: {}", e);
        Response::new(StatusCode::BadRequest, None)
    }
}
```

Implementation of Handler Trait:

```
impl Handler for WebsiteHandler {
    fn handle_request(&mut self, request: &Request) -> Response {
        match request.method() {
            Method::GET => match request.path() {
                "/" => Response::new(StatusCode::Ok, self.read_file("index.html")),
                "/hello" => Response::new(StatusCode::Ok, self.read_file("hello.html")),
                "/sleep" => {
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
                    Response::new(StatusCode::Ok, self.read_file("hello.html"))
                }
                path => match self.read_file(path) {
                    Some(contents) => Response::new(StatusCode::Ok, Some(contents)),
                    None => Response::new(StatusCode::NotFound, None),
                },
            },
            _ => Response::new(StatusCode::NotFound, None),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here. How is `ThreadPool` implemented? What is a `Handler`?

Comment: My guess: the first thread locks the `handler` mutex and sleeps. Then the second thread tries to acquire the lock but can't because it's still held by the first thread, so it blocks until the first thread completes its request and releases the lock.

Comment: @isaactfa, I've updated the post with the implementation of Threadpool and the Handler,

Comment: @Jmb, Thanks for the reply, So I am turning the handler into an Arc Mutex and calling it's functions using lock(), is there a way to not have to use lock?

Comment: Yeah, @Jmb is right, the `Handler` gets locked until the `handle_request` call returns, so only one thread can use it at a time. You could consider making your `Handler` thread safe, using `Arc<Mutex<_>>` internally to synchronize state.